# MySQL partition is full

Tags: mysql, raspbian

I've just installed MySQL (with Apache) on my new Raspberry Pi. When I tried starting it I immediately got this error:

```
df: `/var/lib/mysql/.': No such file or directory
df: no file systems processed
[....] /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full! [FA failed!
```

The RPI is having a 8GB SD Card.

[image]

Output of `du -sch /`:

[image]

### UPDATE 19:30 13/18

I've also found these errors in my PHP error log

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0
```

My SD card isn't full so I don't get the problem?

Comment: Your `/` (where `/var/` is appended) is full: `100%`

Comment: Can't I make room for it? The SD card isn't full at all?

Comment: Looks like you may need to expand the available space on your SD card to use (the majority of) its 8GB

Comment: @Anton : run `fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` (or equivalent `/dev` device) to see how much space the card *really* has. `df`s output is irrelevant if you have space not allocated to any partition.

Answer (score 3):

Your `/` (where `/var/` is appended) is full: `100%`. *On my rasp I'm running nginx with sqlite because apache and mysql use way more resources in general.*

It doesn't look like 8GB in total, according to your `df` output.

Anyways, I guess your log files consume the diskspace.

You can use the following to find the folder which uses much:

```
du -sch /*
```

and:

```
du -sch /var/*
```

Comment: [Screen](http://kutj.es/y28-rn)

Comment: I added the image to your question. The info about `/proc` is normal. But I wonder where the rest of your root folders are?! It only shows `/` and `/var`. Where is `/usr`, `/home`, ..... Please append content of file `/etc/fstab` to the question.

Comment: @Anton Stupid me.. please use `du -sch /*`, with `/*` at the end.

Comment: @Anton should run `fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0' (or equivalent `/dev` device) to see how much space the card *really* has. `df`s output is irrelevant if you have space not allocated to any partition.

Comment: @DanFromGermany [/*](http://i.imgur.com/E2QDp8K.gif) [/var/*](http://kutj.es/333-rp) [/user/*](http://kutj.es/w3o-rq)

Comment: @ValmikyArquissandas http://kutj.es/07a-rr

Comment: @Anton: don't do that to `/dev`, do it to `/dev/mmcblk0`.

Comment: @ValmikyArquissandas http://kutj.es/99x-rs